# Not throwing Null Pointer Exception for Object Type Even default value is NULL

Tags: java, arrays

```
package Sample;
public class Sample4Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println(a[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
        //default value is 0
    }

    Integer x[] = new Integer[10];

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(x[i]);
        //default value is null & not throwing an exception.
    }       
}
}
```

To consider; the first for loop returns 0 as default value & second for loop even its default value is null then also it's not throwing any exception

Answer (score 2):

Which Exception you are expecting to be thrown? NullpointerException?
It won't throw this exception because you are not trying to access any method/variable on the null reference.

What you are seeing is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any `NullPointerException` because

`System.out.println(x[i]);` internally makes use of `String.valueOf()` on `x[i]` to get its string representation.

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

`String.valueOf()` internally checks if the incoming object is null and if yes, it uses the String `null` as its value. See below :

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to throw an `Exception`. You aren't trying to dereference a null pointer. The default value set to an `Integer` Object is `null`. You are simply printing that `null` value. However, if you did try to dereference that `null` value, you would get an error.

If you do only this:

```
Integer[] x;
```

The variable x is *pointing* to a `null` value. You **WILL** get an error now if you try to dereference it.

The moment you do:

```
x = new Integer[10];
```

Memory is being allocated to it using the `new` operator. It no longer points to `null`. Therefore, you don't get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you construct an array of int (primitive) like this `int a[] = new int[10];` the array is created with default values of 0

And when you construct an array of Integer (Object) like this `Integer x[] = new Integer[10];` the array is created with default values of null.So when you try to access any element it will give you its value which is null (null is a value)

But if you tried to do any operation on the returned value it throw null pointer exception

```
x[i].intValue(); //this will give you java.lang.NullPointerException
```

- Default for anything that holds an object is null
- Default for booleans is a false.
- Default for char that is the null character '\u0000' (whose decimal
  equivalent is 0).
- Default for int/short/byte/long that is a 0
- Default for float/double that is a 0.0